# For Loop in Jinja2 with related variables

Tags: python, for-loop, jinja2

I am having difficulty in writing a for loop in a Jinja template that iterates over a variable that contains fruits names and in the body is the characteristics of that fruit that is also provided as variable.

So lets say we have the following variables

```
fruit=apple,banana,grapes
apple_color=red
apple_weight=1kg
banana_color=yellow
banana_weight=2kg
grapes_color=green
grapes_weight=3kg
```

I am having difficulty in creating a for loop that iterates the fruit variable and then in the body calls the variables only specific to the fruit being iterated. So in the first iteration when value is apple, the body must use variables apple_color and apple_weight and similarly for second iteration banana the variables in the body are banana_color and banana_weight.

Does this require using lists for something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
fruits = {'apple' : {'color', apple_color, 'weight' : apple_weight}, 'banana' : {'color' : banana_color, 'weight' : banana_weight}, 'grapes' : {'color' : grapes_color, 'weight' : grapes_weigh}} 

or if you use your already defined variables like  : apple_color = 'red'

fruit_names = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes']
fruits = {}
for each in fruit_names :
    fruits[each] = {}
    fruits[each]['color'] = globals()['%s_%s' %(each, 'color')]
    fruits[each]['weight'] = globals()['%s_%s' %(each, 'weight')]
```

In your template :

```
{% for each in fruits %}
    {{ fruits[each].color }}
    {{ fruits[each].weight }}
{% endfor %}

or :

{% for key, value in fruits.items() %} 
    {{ key }}
    {{ value.color }} 
    {{ value.weight }} 
{% endfor %}
```